# Find a file recursively using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below files located at some location in RHEL machine. 
temp_file2.txt
temp_file3.txt

Looking for a python script to find above files recursively in all directories(I used a wild card, but it didn't work), and print a message if the file exists or not.

The below code snippet returns Nothing

```
import glob

for filename in glob.iglob('*/*.txt', recursive=True):
    print(filename)
```

It returns the file name if it exists only in the current working directory

```
import glob

for filename in glob.iglob('.txt', recursive=True):
    print(filename)
```

Comment: I think you need `**`, so `glob.iglob('**/*.txt', recursive=True):`

Comment: I have tried ** also, and I noticed it returns files in the current working directory only.

Answer (score 1):

This approach seems to have worked for me, using python3.6

```
import glob

for f in glob.iglob('./**/*.yml', recursive=True):
    print(f)
```

I was also able to use `os.getcwd() + '/**/*.yml'`. It appears there must be a directory definition at the start of the glob.